# MongoDB query is executing slow even though I am using indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This is an example of the type of document I store on my Calls collection:

```json
{
    "_id" : "CL-33094E07D8C136ECA578",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-03-30T16:27:55.605-04:00"),        
    "CallerIdNum" : "+19546543985",
    "To" : "+13054595694",
    "Status" : "STARTING",
    "CallType" : "Incoming",    
    "Id_Account" : "1",        
    "HasRecording" : true,   
    "HasVoicemail" : true,                    
    "Id_DID" : "PN6a7910b42f2ad4ce38946f451a24c2",
    "IdTrunkOrigination" : "TK47546477f456b8be9b9f7faf46bc05",        
    "CallerIdNum_Reversed" : "58934564591+",
    "To_Reversed" : "+13054595694"
}
```

I want to give users the option to search for specific phone calls so I have created this form:

[image]

I don't like compound indexes because I don't know in advance what fields someone wants to search for. For example someone may be interested on searching for phone calls that have a voicemail and that comes from phone number that ends with 3885. Or They may be interested on getting phone calls received by DID 305-321-4388 and that have a recording. **How can I solve this problem? There are a lot of combinations and it does not make sense to create that many compound indexes.**

Anyways since there are lots of combinations I separated the form so that the user can only search for Incoming phone calls and on a separate form outgoing phone calls. That way I am sure that all my queries will have at least this 3 filters:

1. Id Account (Id_Account)
2. If call is incoming our outgoing (CallType)
3. Date Range (DateCreated)

As a result I have created my first compund index like this:

```
db.Calls.createIndex({Id_Account:1, CallType:1, DateCreated:1})
```

So far that has helped a lot but queries still take a while to execute if you add additional parameters.

Since it makes no sense to create all combinations of compound indexes I only want to create compound indexes of the combinations that are most likely to be used. For example users usually want to find phone calls from a specific phone number that where received by a particular DID. DID stands for Direct inward dialing and its a phone number that a provider such as AT&T gives you so that you can receive phone calls.

So now I know that it is very common for users to search for Calls using the fields:

1. Id_DID
2. CallerIdNum_Reversed

*We use CallerIdNum_Reversed so that the query can execute faster. We place an index on that field and search for all fields that start with some pattern. Because sometimes the caller id number comes with the +1 and sometimes it does not we just ask the user to enter the last digits of the phone number he is interested on searching for.*

As a result I have created the following compound index:

```
db.Calls.createIndex({Id_Account:1, CallType:1, DateCreated:1, Id_DID:1, CallerIdNum_Reversed:1 })
```

**Why is it that this query below takes 9 seconds to execute even though I am using that compound index?**

```
db.getCollection('Calls').find(
 { 
     'Id_Account' : '11', 
     'CallType' : 'Incoming' , 
     'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2017-10-02T04:00:00Z') } , 'DateCreated' : { '$lte': ISODate('2021-10-03T04:59:59Z') } ,
     'Id_DID' : '525552812424',
     'CallerIdNum_Reversed' : /^3985/     
 }
)
```

Comment: did you tried Explain? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/ Also i feel you can combine DateCreated condition into one... however it should not be cause for slowness of query      'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2017-10-02T04:00:00Z') ,'$lte': ISODate('2021-10-03T04:59:59Z') } ,

Comment: It examines 347,744 keys with the Explain("executionStats") appended to the end of the query. Why does it examines that many keys if I am searching by all the fields on the compound index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was not ANDing the date range :/

replaced the line:

```
'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2017-10-02T04:00:00Z') } , 'DateCreated' : { '$lte': ISODate('2021-10-03T04:59:59Z') }
```

for

```
'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2017-10-02T04:00:00Z'),'$lte': ISODate('2021-10-03T04:59:59Z') }
```